# AngularJs Checkbox Function

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I want to change my background-color to lightblue when the value of the checkbox is true, and change the background-color back to normal when the value is false.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in rows | filter:search" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}">
```

My Checkbox:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)"></td>
```

My Function:

```js
$scope.selected = null;  
$scope.setClickedRow = function(index){  
    $scope.selectedRow = index;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a plunker with your example: http://plnkr.co/edit/CHB65fe6Bsd3PdjWjoT4?p=preview

This is the table:

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr ng-repeat="item in rows | filter:search" ng-class="{'selected': item.selected}">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model= "item.selected" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```